# Implementing 3 blocks with CSS

Tags: css

I want my page to have 3 blocks: LEFT CENTER RIGHT. I want block LEFT and RIGHT is about 150px wide, and block CENTER just fill up the rest of the space. There are 10px gap between the each block. Here is my attempt:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 800px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 800px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#center {        
    margin: 2px 160px 0 160px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

If I dont have the `#center`, the block LEFT and RIGHT (gray color) look great. But when i try to fill the white space in the center with a Yellow block, it mess up. I cant see my RIGHT block anymore.

Comment: Argh. A real can of worms. Look for "Holy Grail" and cross your fingers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're describing is known as the "Holy Grail layout" (for good reason!) See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail for a good article on it or google "CSS Holy Grail Layout" for more.

Comment: Reading it now. Definitely look like the answer to my problem. Thanks +1

Comment: This is ideal if you want the height to scale with your content and a single page-level scroller. The solution I provided is more ideal if you would like your three areas to always be full screen with individual scrollers in each block.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work in all standard browsers (IE7 and later, firefox, chrome, opera, safari). (If you must have IE6 support, I can provide a updated example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Example</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
#MainContainerPanel
{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
}
#LeftPanel
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:150px;
    overflow:auto; /* change to hidden if you dont want scrolling */
    background-color:red; /*to clarify layout is working*/
}
#CenterPanel
{
    position:absolute;
    left:160px;
    right:160px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow:auto; /* change to hidden if you dont want scrolling */
    background-color:green; /*to clarify layout is working*/
}
#RightPanel
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:150px;
    overflow:auto; /* change to hidden if you dont want scrolling */
    background-color:blue; /*to clarify layout is working*/
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainContainerPanel">
        <div id="LeftPanel">This is the left panel</div>
        <div id="CenterPanel">This is the center panel</div>
        <div id="RightPanel">This is the right panel</div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with absolute positioning:

```
#left
{
    width:150px;
}

#center
{
    left:150px;
    right:150px;
}

#right
{
    right:0px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Note that the parent of all the boxes must have `position:relative`, as absolute positioning is relative to the first `position:relative` ancestor (or `body` if there isn't one...or actually maybe `html`. I'm not sure. The browser window, at least). There are reasons not to use absolute positioning, though, so this may not work in your particular case. For example, the columns will not all be equal height (unless you explicitly bind the height), so if you want different backgrounds on the columns this will probably not look right. Also, cross-browser compatibility is definitely an issue.